# ruby dynamic function call

Tags: ruby, dynamic

Trying to do a dynamic test suite and re-use function definitions.  I have a form where you can pick different types of ways that someone can contact you, and the page will display differently based on the method of contact.  I am trying to do

```
When /^I click the (.*) return type$/ do |response|
  on_page(ContactUsPage).response unless @browser.url.include?("contactBy=#{response}")
```

This will take the current type of response and click the link unless the url includes "contactBy=" and the response type (meaning you're already on the page and there is no link to click)

I have a page object class (ContactUsPage) that has links for the different methods (email, phone, fax, postal)

the problem i'm having is with the `ContactUsPage.response`  response is getting injected into the browser check, but it's looking for a method "response" inside ContactUsPage instead of injecting the method.

The method should call `ContactUsPage.email` or `ContactUsPage.fax` or `ContactUsPage.phone` depending on the method passed into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ruby's [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) method to invoke a method dynamically:

```
on_page(ContactUsPage).send(response)
```

`send`'s first argument  is a string or symbol with the method name to be invoked; any further arguments are passed to the method itself. For example, `foo.send(:bar, "baz")` is equivalent to `foo.bar("baz")`

If you want to call a method that *starts* with the variable name (`email_element` or similar), you just need to do a quick string interpolation:

```
on_page(ContactUsPage).send("#{response}_element")
# equivalent to `on_page(ContactUsPage).email_element` when response == "email"
```

Comment: can you use this method while using the _element attribute? on_page(ContactUsPage).send(response)_element.exists?.should be_true is giving me an error after (response) "expected end of line"

Comment: Yeah, that isn't valid Ruby syntax. `send` needs the full name of the method you expect it to invoke. See my edited answer for the correct approach.

Comment: i don't think your understanding the _element part.  _element is a function given to you by page object. Example: link(:email,x). if you use email, you get the value of x, email_element returns the element from the page

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understood. You want to call `email_element`, `fax_element`, and so on, right? `send("#{response}_element")` does exactly that.